# Request Pooling Nginx-Gunicorn-Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am using Nginx - Gunicorn - Django - Mysql for one of my b2c applications..

The problem is when number of users accessing my app grows, MySql starts throwing too many connections.. I have the following options -

1. Increase number of mysql connections - Done made it 500
2. Use MySQL connection pooling - Sub standard solutions using SQLAlchemy - Not sure
3. Do Http request connection pooling - Throttle number of requests being served at a time

I need help with 2 and 3 above.. I need some throttling for the incoming requests so that I do not run out of MySQL connections or other resources..

Comment: There's something very wrong with your setup. I don't believe you have more than 500 gunicorn processes going at once.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The number of gunicorn processes are as per the formula 2*core +1.. so it is 3 for us..

Comment: Right. So how can 3 gunicorn processes be using 500 MySQL connections?